# CollectionAssert.AreNotEqual even though I am resetting the values in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am new to C# and trying to learn unit testing. I have a unit test that sets a list of guesses for a guessing game and stores them in a session. However, the unit tests fails.

My unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void StartNewGameCausesANewTargetInTheGuessingGameGameStoredInSessionState()
{
    //Arrange
    var theGame = new GuessingGame();
    List<int> originalTarget = new List<int>(theGame.Target);
    var theContext = new FakeHttpContext();
    var theKey = "GameState";
    theContext.Session.Add(theKey, theGame);
    var controller = new Exercise09Controller();
    var request = new System.Web.Routing.RequestContext(theContext, new System.Web.Routing.RouteData());
    controller.ControllerContext = new System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext(request, controller);

    //Act
    controller.StartNewGame();

    //Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(controller.Session[theKey], typeof(GuessingGame));
    CollectionAssert.AreNotEqual(originalTarget, theGame.Target);
}
```

My Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Prigmore2013_01.Models
{
    public class GuessingGame
    {
        private Random _random;

        public GuessingGame()
        {
            this.Guesses = new List<Guess>();
            this.Target = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
            this._random = new Random();
        }


        public List<int> Target { get; set; }
        public List<Guess> Guesses { get; set; }

        public List<Guess> ShowGuessesMade()
        {
            return Guesses;
        }


        public void NewGame()
        {
            this.Target.Clear();
            var count = 4;
            for (var i = 1; i < count; i++)
            {
                var swap = _random.Next(1, 9);

                if (!this.Target.Contains(swap))
                {
                    this.Target.Add(swap);
                }


                // need to create a new random in generator
            }


        }


        public void GuessTheHiddenDigits(List<int> guesses)
        {

            Guess g = new Guess() { Digits = guesses };


            //compare the lists
            var list = this.Target;
            var list2 = g.Digits;

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                if (list[i] == list2[i])
                {
                    g.RightDigitRightPosition++;
                }
            }

            //Now calculate how many digits in guesses are just plain wrong
            List<int> result = g.Digits.Except(this.Target).ToList();
            g.RightDigitWrongPosition = g.Digits.Count - result.Count - g.RightDigitRightPosition;

            //handle duplicates
            if (list.Count != list2.Distinct().Count())
            {
                // set thet right digit wrong position
                for (int i = 0; i < list2.Distinct().Count(); i++ )
                {
                    g.RightDigitWrongPosition = i;
                }

            }
            this.Guesses.Add(g);
        } 
    }
}
```

In my controller I trying to set `Target` in my `StartNewGame()` am I doing this correctly:

```
public RedirectToRouteResult StartNewGame()
        {

            var count = 4;
            var random = new Random();
            var result = new List<int>();

            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var swap = random.Next(1, 9);

                if (!result.Contains(swap))
                {
                    result.Add(swap);
                }


                // need to create a new random in generator
            }
            this.Session["GameState"] = new GuessingGame() { Target = result };

            return RedirectToRoute(new
            {
                controller = "Index",
                action = "Index"
            });
        }
```

I fear that the problem is being caused in my GuessingGame constructor as it sets the target as `List<int>() {1,2,3}` and this is then not getting overwritten. How would I create a new list of different ints and then set them as my session?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your unit test you are using `theGame`, a local variable, for your comparison. You should instead rewrite your second assertion to this:

```
var sessionGame = controller.Session[theKey] as GuessingGame;
CollectionAssert.AreNotEqual(originalTarget, sessionGame.Target);
```

Your controller is not working with `theGame`, it is creating its own instance of `GuessingGame` and setting the session variable accordingly. Your first assertion shows you understand this, but you are just missing the understanding about what instance of your class the controller is working with.

I trust you realize that with your random number generation there is still an off-chance that the contents of the 2 List collections could be the same.